# What're pairwise, vertex disjoint copies of $K_5$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I need some help nailing some graph theory terminologies down. I know that a planar graph $G$, is a graph where no two edges intersect one another. A vertex disjoint graph $G1$ is a graph, where $V(G1_1) \ \cap V(G1_2)=\emptyset$, or each sub graph of $G1$ don't share any edges. $K_5$ is a non-planar graph which has $5$ vertices which're connected to one another by edges. However I'm unsure as to what pairwise, vertex disjoint copies of $K_5$ are. It would be great if someone can explain in intuitive English what that is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one $K_5$: a graph with $5$ vertices (which I've numbered $1$ to $5$), with an edge connecting each pair of vertices.

[image]

Here are two vertex-disjoint copies of $K_5$.  Ten vertices ($1$ to $10$).  The first five form one copy of $K_5$, since each pair of them is connected by an edge.  The second five form the other copy of $K_5$, again each pair connected by an edge.  They are vertex-disjoint since no vertex in the first five is in the second five.

[image]

BTW: your statement about a planar graph is faulty.  A planar graph is one **that can be drawn so that** no two edges cross each other.  This is a planar graph, even though there are crossing edges in the picture:

[image]

because you **can** draw it so those edges don't cross:

[image]

Comment: So if you wanted to you could make as many vertex disjoint copies of $K_5$ as you wanted, as long as the vertices are different? Also what would **pairwise** vertex disjoint copies of $K_5$?

Comment: **Pairwise** vertex disjoint just means each pair of copies are vertex disjoint.

Comment: So pairwise vertex disjoint copies just refers to the graph having $x$ many pair copies of $K_5$ such that each copy is vertex disjoint from the others? In this case, if we say that there are $6$ pairwise vertex disjoint copies of $K_5$, then there are $6$ five form graphs and in total $30$ vertices.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: So what's the maximum amount of pairwise vertex disjoint copies of $K_5$ can $G$, $G$ is $5$ planar, have? I know on the minimum side, it's zero because if we have $K_5$ with a vertex $6$ connected to $5$ and a new vertex $7$, where $7$ is connected to $4$ and $5$. If you remove vertex $1$ to $5$ you're just left with vertex $6$ and $7$, which is not a copy of $K_5$.

Comment: Would we have to consider the copies as blocks and then try to work with those?